# What is wrong with this JQuery code?

Tags: jquery

```
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">                                         

//waits till the document is ready
$(document).ready(function() {
    //onclick function
    $('button.butter').click(function(){
        //code will only run on certain url
        if (pathname.indexOf("google")>= 0){
            alert('This doesn't work anymore!');  

           //replacer
          $("a[href*='https://google.com']").attr('href',('http://www.google.com/search?q' + $('#FormID').val()));
        }
        else{
            alert('Wrong page');
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

It doesn't alert, but why? This was working earlier and I forgot to save it. It should replace the url with another one plus the value from a field. edit: head, html, etc. tags are there.

```
<button class="butter">Press</button>
```

Comment: For your first alert(), you need to escape the ' in doesn't, right?

Comment: check the web console and add alert('This dosen\'t work anymore'); instead of what you have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `location.pathname` rather than `pathname`

Answer (score 0):

You don't declare `pathname` anywhere, this:

```
if (pathname.indexOf("google")>= 0){
```

should result in an error in your console.